# IndexError: list index out of range, snake game

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, pygame

```
'''
Created on 13.3.2016
worm game
@author: Hai
'''
import pygame
import random
from pygame import * ##

class Worm:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = surface.get_width() / 2
        self.y = surface.get_height() / 2
        self.length = 1
        self.grow_to = 50
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False
        self.color = 255, 255, 0

    def key_event(self, event):
        """ Handle keyboard events that affect the worm. """
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP and self.vy != 1:
            self.vx = 0
            self.vy = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and self.vx != -1:
            self.vx = 1
            self.vy = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and self.vy != -1:
            self.vx = 0
            self.vy = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and self.vx != 1:
            self.vx = -1
            self.vy = 0

    def move(self):
        """ Moving worm """
        self.x += self.vx # add vx to x
        self.y += self.vy

        if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True

        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))

        # Changes worm to right size so it is grow_to
        if self.grow_to > self.length: 
            self.length += 1

        # If body is longer than length then pop
        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()
    """            
    def draw(self):

        self.surface.set_at((int(self.x), int(self.y)), (255, 255, 255))
        self.surface.set_at((int(self.last[0]),int(self.last[1])), (0,0,0))
    """
    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    def eat(self):
        self.grow_to += 25

    def draw(self):

        x, y = self.body[0]
        self.surface.set_at((int(x), int(y)), self.color)
        x, y = self.body[-1]
        self.surface.set_at((int(x), int(y)), (0, 0, 0))

    #    for x, y in self.body:
    #        self.surface.set_at((int(x), int(y)), self.color)
    #        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 6, 6), 0)
    # worm's head


class Food:
    def __init__(self, surface):
            self.surface = surface
            self.x = random.randint(0, surface.get_width())
            self.y = random.randint(0, surface.get_height())
            self.color = 255,255,255

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.set_at((int(self.x),int(self.y)), self.color)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 6, 6), 0)

    def position(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    """ Check if worm have eaten this food """
    def check(self, x, y):
        if x < self.x or x > self.x + 6:
            return False
        elif y < self.y or y > self.y + 6:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def erase(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (0,0,0), (int(self.x), int(self.y), 6, 6), 0)        



w = h = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.init()
chomp = pygame.mixer.Sound("bow.wav")

score = 0
worm = Worm(screen) ###
food = Food(screen)
running = True

while running:
    # screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) optimized in worm draw()
    worm.draw()
    food.draw()
    worm.move()


    if worm.crashed or worm.x <= 0 or worm.x >= w-1 or worm.y <= 0 or worm.y >= h-1:
        print("U lose")
        running = False
    elif food.check(worm.x, worm.y):
        worm.eat()
        food.erase()
        chomp.play()
        score += 1
        print("Score is: %d" % score)
        food = Food(screen)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Pressed X
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # When pressing keyboard
            worm.key_event(event)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)
```

hello i am getting error 
x, y = self.body[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
and i am doing this tutorial:
https://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/pygame-tutorial-9-first-improvements-to-the-game/

I am very new to python, plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your class's `__init__` function, you define `self.body = []`. This means that the list contains 0 items.

Later in your code, you reference `self.body[0]` and `self.body[1]`, which are the first and second items in the list. Since these do not exist, an error is raised. To fix this, you need to initialize `self.body` with two items.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the order of the operations you are doing, your `body` list is actually still empty. Follow the logic of your code, and you will see.

You start by instantiating your worm here:

```
worm = Worm(screen) ###
```

So, if you look at the `__init__` of `Worm`, you are setting `self.body` to an empty list `[]`.

If you follow all the code that happens from then until you actually call:

```
worm.draw()
```

You are never actually inserting anything on to your `body` list. So, when you try to access your body list inside your `draw` method:

```
error x, y = self.body[0]
```

You are definitely going to get an index out of range error, since there is nothing to access.

To rectify this you need to either provide a default like:

```
# arbitrary data
self.body = [0, 0]
```

Or, determine in your draw method how to handle empty lists using some condition like:

```
if self.body:
    # do things
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Worm's `__init__` function you can set `self.body[]` to `self.body[(0, 0)]`, this works. The error is raised because you defined an empty list at the beginning and later you tried to get an item from the list by passing an index (`self.body[0]`). But because the list is empty, Python cannot get the asked value.

Hope this helps!